# Android: sort by date in the JSON data

Tags: android, sorting, date, parsing, android-asynctask

I am new to Android. I'm trying to sort by the date in the JSON data, but nothing works. I'm not even getting an error. I've tried so many different ways, but its not working.

I did a lot of searching but could not figure out how to implement this. How can I sort this by the days column? Thank you in advance.

Here's my code

```
public class ParseJSONTask  extends AsyncTask< Void , Void , Void > {
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Activity act = null;
private  static String TAG_SERVICES = "services";
private static String TAG_ID = "id";
private static String TAG_COMMAND = "command";
private static String TAG_DAYS = "days";
private static String TAG_HOURS = "hours";
private static String TAG_OSMS = "osms";
private static String TAG_ISMS = "isms";
private static String TAG_TIMEOUT = "timeout";
public String SMS_SENT = "SMS Gönderildi";
public String SMS_DELIVERED = "SMS İletildi";
public String serviceString = "";

ArrayList<ServiceData> services;

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        services = new ArrayList<ServiceData>();


    }
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        WebServiceHandler webServiceHandler = new WebServiceHandler();
        String JsonStr = webServiceHandler.getJSONData("http://jsonblob.com/55e34310e4b01190df36e861");

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JsonStr);
            final JSONArray contactsJSON = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_SERVICES);

            for (int i = 0; i < contactsJSON.length(); i++) {

                ServiceData aServiceData = new ServiceData();


                //json parse  istedimiz veriyi kullanabiliriz.
                JSONObject serviceObject = contactsJSON.getJSONObject(i);

                aServiceData.id = serviceObject.getString(TAG_ID);

                aServiceData.command = serviceObject.getString(TAG_COMMAND);

                aServiceData.days = serviceObject.getString(TAG_DAYS);

                aServiceData.hours = serviceObject.getString(TAG_HOURS);

                aServiceData.osms = serviceObject.getString(TAG_OSMS);

                aServiceData.isms = serviceObject.getString(TAG_ISMS);

                aServiceData.timeout = serviceObject.getString(TAG_TIMEOUT);


                String input = aServiceData.days + " " + aServiceData.hours;
                Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(input);
                long milliseconds = date.getTime();
                final long millisecondsFromNow = milliseconds - (new Date()).getTime();
                aServiceData.milliseconds = milliseconds;
                services.add(aServiceData);

                if(millisecondsFromNow > 0) {
                    new DateSendSMS().onCreate(aServiceData.days, aServiceData.hours, aServiceData.osms, aServiceData.command);
                    Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(aServiceData.timeout) * 60000);
                }

                //Timeout aşağı kısımda sürelendirilecek


            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String serviceString = "";
        for (ServiceData aServiceData:services){
            serviceString+=aServiceData.toString();
        }
        Collections.sort(services, new Comparator<ServiceData>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ServiceData t1, ServiceData t2) {
                return t1.milliseconds <= t2.milliseconds ? -1 : 1;
            }
        });

        // here is sorted data
        for (ServiceData aServiceData : services) {

            // move DateSendSMS here. above you can add additional logic about millis
            new DateSendSMS().onCreate(aServiceData.days, aServiceData.hours, aServiceData.osms, aServiceData.command);
            Log.d("+++++", aServiceData.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

ServiceData Class:

```
public static class ServiceData {
    public long milliseconds;
    public String id = "";
    public String command = "";
    public String days = "";
    public String hours = "";
    public String osms = "";
    public String isms = "";
    public String timeout = "";
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + ",  " + command + ",  " + days + ",  " + hours + ",  " + osms + ",  " + isms
                + ",  " + timeout + "\n \n  ";
    }
}
```

Comment: after parsing and formatting date try to put in any Collection like List or Arraylist and then apply Collection.sort().

Comment: yes I understand the logic in this way but it does not change the result when I apply

Comment: I updated your code to log sorted data. now start the task, and check result. `// here is sorted data`  in `onPostExecute`

Comment: @UmutADALI so, are you satisfied?

Comment: @StasParshin yes thanks

Comment: For friends who have the same problems, using Kotlin makes more sense for asynctask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add time field to `ServiceData` class

```
ServiceDate {
   ...
   long milliseconds;
   ...
}
```

Fill this field in for loop:

```
long milliseconds = date.getTime();
aServiceData.milliseconds = milliseconds;
```

Sort `services` in `onPostExecute`

```
Collections.sort(services, new Comparator<ServiceData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ServiceData t1, ServiceData t2) {
        return t1.milliseconds <= t2.milliseconds ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Really? is it sorted for some other way or full unsorted?

Comment: @Diode it's interesting for me too, but you can fix this :) i saw your answer was down-voted too. somebody angry is walking here

Comment: im new so votes can not use votes :) I tried something similar before, nothing has changed at all. I think I am making a mistake somewhere

Comment: @UmutADALI did you add `aServiceData.milliseconds = milliseconds;` in you for loop? post you new code through question editing

Comment: @UmutADALI yeah, i checked, excellent sorted data. i added log in your `onPostExecute`. check by yourself, data is sorted by date

Comment: @pengrad yes I realized afterwards, sort is working in OnPostExecute, but DateSendSMS class not working in the right place. 
its send compared to first sending json sorting. Do I have to write for loop again, I perform exactly where

Comment: @UmutADALI do what you need with data in `onPostExecute` after sorting, i updated code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can directly sort Json Data (I dont know weather there is a library that will actually do it -  if so go for it). I Suggest you to put all the `ServiceData` into a collection (Which you do at the moment) and then Sort it.

You can write your own sorting algorithm or you can use a `Java Collections library` to do the sorting by implimention Comparable on your ServiceData class or using a Comparable and them you can use `Colletions.sort()` to sort your list.

[Here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/) is a good tutorial.

Comment: i check this tutorial before, but somehow did not apply to my code

Comment: @UmutADALI Hey I dot see your sorting in your code,

Comment: because its not working. I just started, so I'm not sure I made the right delete

Comment: @UmutADALI paste your ServiceData class

Comment: i added ServiceData Class.